# How do I access facebook friend's information like bday using android app programmatically with latest facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access all my friend information using android app. But the sample which I found online are outdated. So can someone suggest me some tutorial to do the same ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in API v2.0 and later. All friends permission was removed. You can read about it more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog